Erro when using next-ui grid in next.js app
I created a generic next.js app (using app router) and added nextui to the app. I added the NextUIProvider component to my RootLayout per the instructions at nextui-org
import {NextUIProvider} from "@nextui-org/react";
...
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
         <NextUIProvider>
          <Header />
            {children}
            <Footer />
         </NextUIProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

I then created a file called "Topics.jsx" and added the next-ui grid component (notice that  I needed to add the 'use client' directive).
But when I run the app, I get the error message: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Container')"
'use client'
import {Grid, Card,Text} from "@nextui-org/react";
import "@app/globals.css";

export default function Topics() {
  return (
    <Grid.Container gap={2} justify="center">
      <Grid xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
        <p>Hello world</p>
      </Grid>
    </Grid.Container>
  );
}

Any thoughts?

I believe Grid component was removed from NextUi v2.x since it's using Tailwind now. Your link is pointing to v1.
My best guess is that you've actually installed NextUi v2.0
